# VSTS release completion failure alert for automated deployment

Tags: azure-devops, release-management

I have a branch in a VSTS project that builds automatically on code push. The release also triggers automatically on the build being completed ('continuous deployment trigger').

This works fine.

If the build fails, I receive an email alert. However if the release fails, I don't receive an email alert. If I trigger the release manually (deployment trigger = manual deployment) and the release fails, then I receive an email.

I think this is because whilst I'm signed up to the 'Deployment completion failures' email subscription, as I don't technically 'request' the build under CI/CD (it's requested under 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement').

Is there a way I can receive emails when the automated release fails? More specifically, how can I set up CI/CD in VSTS where if the release fails, the person who requested the build that triggered the release receives an email?

Edit: Screenshot requested.[image]

Comment: This shouldn't happen. From where did you find out that Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement is the identity triggering the deployment? Release history tab ?

Comment: The accounts of release created by and Deployment request for should be the user who queue the build. Do you create a new release subscription with deployment completed that deliver to Deployment requested for, release requested by role? What's the detail setting of your subscription? (`https://XXX.visualstudio.com/[team project]/_admin/_notifications`) BTW: the default subscription will be trigger if last deployment is succeed or partially succeed and current deployment is failed or cancelled.

Comment: @Harshil Yes, it's in the release history tab. The user is marked as 'creating' the release (triggered by build) and then the MS.VS.S.RM user is marked as the user for queued, triggered, and succeeded deployment.

Comment: @starain As far as I'm aware, we haven't modified any of the default subscriptions - however if what you're saying is true around the default rules, it sounds like you only get a notification if the release fails (or is cancelled) - can i set it up so that the default notification is that it sends an alert even if it's successful on a GLOBAL level? or do i need to change this on each project individually?

Comment: Yes, you can add a collection level subscription, go to `https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_notifications?view=subscribers`, select a user or group, then click New subscription with Any team project filter. On the other hand, can you provide the screenshot of release history?

Comment: @starain that's great - that does exactly what i was after. Maybe it's how I'm using VSTS but I thought it strange that the trigger-er receives an email by default saying the build completed, but not an email by default that says the release completed!

Comment: Does the original issue has been solved? Based on the screenshot the release is created by Benjamin, so he should receive the email if there is the subscription meets.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was as per starian chen's suggestion to add a collection level subscription.